# htaccess - "detect" url and redirect

Tags: apache, htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, localhost

Idea is:

```
if      URL = "http:/localhost/site/"
else if URL = "http:/localhost/site"
```

redirect to

```
"http:/localhost/site/index.html"
```

**Can this be done with .htaccess / Apache mod_rewrite** and how?

Comment: Yes, it can be done with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Why aren't you using `DirectoryIndex index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

You could simple add this in your htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

Comment: Why not the main Apache configuration file? Apache re-reads, re-parses, and re-configures whenever it discovers an `.htaccess` file in the directory structure. You might as well promote the mechanism that has the least impact...